# Hibernate exception on startup

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, nhibernate-mapping

I have just started learning Hibernate. For that I have written a simple Java Program.
But when I try to execute the program I am getting following exception.

```
Apr 30, 2014 1:54:18 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Apr 30, 2014 1:54:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:293)
    at com.hiber.main.Main.main(Main.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:221)
    ... 4 more
```

Following is the program:

```
package com.hiber.main;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        //SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build());

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("/com/hiber/main/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();

        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.setTest1Ind(1);
        t.setName("name");
        t.setPassword("abcd1234");
        sess.saveOrUpdate(t);

        sess.getTransaction().commit();
        sess.close();


    }

}
```

Following is the cfg xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root1234</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have included all the dependencies. Hopefully I haven't missed anything. 
Can't add image currently.

Please anyone have a look at the code and spare a thought on what might be going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say `cfg xml` but in your code reference it as `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Have you unzipped your generated JAR and checked the file is indeed where your code says it is?

Answer (score 0):

Have the hibernate.cfg.xml in the classpath and try with the code like this

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

For example if you use maven, it will be in location `\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml`

**Updated:**

Check if you have the right dependencies (jars).
I have these dependencies in my maven project

[image]

Comment: I am running application as Eclipse project. I have tried with the above code too but still same exception. Plus to not miss the classpath I have copied cfg file under SRC folder. I hope this should be enough to have it in classpath ?

Comment: If you keep inside src folder, try with configuration.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: Other option try with the full complete path including the drive. For example C:/Users/jjayarman/Google Drive/Java Trials/hibernate_434/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(new File("D:\\gaurav\\softwares\\spring_install_suite\\ws\\Hiber\\src\\hibernate.cfg.xml"));  this failed as well and gave same exception.

Comment: Ok what are the libraries (jars) you have in the classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial [here](http://macjavashop.blogspot.com/2014/01/maven-hibernate-one-to-one-mapping.html)

its about step by step Hibernate Mapping using Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the mapping class at hibernate cfg.

add mapping class before tag

```
</session-factory>
```

at your hibernate cfg and don't forget to add the annotation at your class.

and the mapping looks like this:

```
<mapping class="Curriculums"/>
<mapping class="CurriculumsHasStudentId"/>
<mapping class="Students"/>
```

your java class with the annotation looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Students implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="studentsNrp", unique=true)
private String studentsNrp;

@Column(name = "studentsName")
private String studentsName;

@Column(name = "studentsAddress")
private String studentsAddress;

@Column(name = "studentsCity")
private String studentsCity;

@Column(name = "studentsPhone")
private String studentsPhone;
```

Comment: Yes I added the mapping class but still same issue.

Comment: have you added the annotation on your java class?

Answer (score 0):

1 Remove the dependencies in your project.
2 Add the right dependencies (jars).