# Issues getting my Hibernate to work

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn Hibernate and now i am stuck with this exception

```
 Hibernate test 
May 01, 2015 10:24:16 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
May 01, 2015 10:24:16 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.9.Final}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:295)
    at com.connector.HibernateSession.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSession.java:18)
    at com.connector.HibernateSession.<clinit>(HibernateSession.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:221)
    ... 6 more
```

The Hibernate class for setting up the connection is like this.

```
package com.connector;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateSession {
    private static  final SessionFactory sessionfactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private HibernateSession(){}

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }


    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionfactory;
    }
}
```

My hibernate config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost</property>
    <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   <!--  <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The structure of my test project

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think this line is enough `new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();` to initialize your session factory provided your `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in your classpath :)

Comment: I think your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is not in correct path. It should be directly under `build/classes` directory with default configuration that you're using

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383635/hibernate-exception-on-startup

Comment: I managed to sort it out. The hibernate.cfg.xml contained an error.